# _yoast_wpseo_title/_yoast_wpseo_metadesc for a taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I would like to make some bulk edits on the above field for the taxonomies on my site. However, after having examined in detail all the tables and fields, I have been unable to find them for the taxonomies.

I have the table `wp_termmeta` EMPTY, and I tried to add the above fields on the table, but it did not work.

Any ideas about how can I make those bulk edits for the field `_yoast_wpseo_title` / `_yoast_wpseo_metadesc` for a taxonomy?

Comment: Have you looked in `wp_options` table?

Comment: Thank you @kale_b you were right.  I  was looking into wrong database (good lesson not to keep db copy near the actual database)

Answer (score 0):

As  @cale_b correclty mentioned, the mentioned taxonomies are stored in `wp_options` table and can be queried with this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_options` WHERE `option_name` = 'wpseo_taxonomy_meta'
```